# Adjectives to describe a legal system that has a number of limitations

Tags: adjectives, legalese

Im finding an adjective describing a judicial system that has many limitations like the system has lax regulations and sanctions are not harsh enough. Looking forward to your replies.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to a **permissive** legal system

- Granting or inclined to grant permission; tolerant or lenient.